# CSS Dotted Border

Tags: html, css

I want to have a dotted border around the "sub" div.. seen below:

```
<div class="navigation">

    <div class="dropdown orange" align="center">                
        <a href="" class="box">ABOUT US</a>
        <div class="sub"> 
            <a href="">STAFF</a>
            <a href="">POLICY</a>
            <a href="">NEWSLETTER</a>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

So I have the CSS:

```
.navigation .dropdown .sub{
    border: 5px dotted #F28845;
}
```

But the border that appears is solid...?

Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1y0vunc8/1/

Thanks for any help.

Comment: ...appears solid cause the border is placed OVER the parent orange background in the padding area

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because it is the same color of your `div` `.dropdown orange`. therefore the `background-color` of `dropdown orange` gets mixed with the `border` of `.sub`

here is a snippet with a different color:

```css
.navigation {
  margin-top: 20px;
  width: 980px;
}
.navigation .dropdown {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 12px;
  vertical-align: top;
}
/*.navigation .dropdown .sub{
 visibility:hidden;
}
.navigation .dropdown:hover .sub{
 visibility:visible;
}*/

.navigation .dropdown:last-child {
  margin: 0px;
}
.navigation .dropdown a {
  display: table;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.navigation .dropdown a:not(.box) {
  background: #FFF;
  width: 100%;
  color: #000;
}
.navigation .dropdown a.box {
  padding: 20px 35px;
  color: #FFF;
}
.navigation .dropdown .sub {
  border: 5px dotted red; /*HERE*/
}
.navigation .dropdown .sub a {
  padding: 5px 0px;
}
.navigation .dropdown.green {
  background: #67B146;
}
.navigation .dropdown.orange {
  background: #F28845;
}
.navigation .dropdown.purple {
  background: #9C52A0;
}
.navigation .dropdown.blue {
  background: #60C9DE;
}
.navigation .dropdown.yellow {
  background: #EFCB35;
}
.navigation .dropdown.red {
  background: #CB4B27;
}
```

```html
<div class="navigation">
  <div class="dropdown orange" align="center">
    <a href="" class="box">ABOUT US</a>
    <div class="sub">
      <a href="">STAFF</a>
      <a href="">POLICY</a>
      <a href="">NEWSLETTER</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply move the class `orange` to your `.box` element:

```
<a href="" class="box orange">ABOUT US</a>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/1y0vunc8/2/

than just change this classing in CSS:

```
.navigation .dropdown .orange{
```

Doing so you'll have the orange background only for the "ABOUT US" *title*, instead for the whole element like you did.